# Android volley is not working in mobile ideal state?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Here I am using android volley for communication. Depends on my requirement I start the communication every 3 mins, At the time, When my device is in active mode means(unlocked mode), the communication will happended properly, but when the device is get locked, that time the communication using volley is not working. after when i unlock the device that time only the communication was started.

```
> StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestedUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String responseFromServer) {},
              new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError errorResponse) {});
context.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Please suggest some answer for me, thanks in advance

Comment: More context needed, where do you have this code?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: sorry for late reply, it is in BroadCastReceiver

Comment: thank you for suggestion guys i got the answer. I got the app reference from service class.